# How to superscript variable using raw string in python

Tags: python, string, matplotlib, superscript, raw

I am using pyplot and numpy in python to show the plots of x^s where s = {2,3,4,5} and iterating for x^s and x^s. When using 'fr' to import my variable 'x' and its negative value, the superscript is only working for '-' and not '-2' for example. My code is as follows:

```
s = [2, 3, 4, 5]

for count, x in enumerate(s):
    x1 = numpy.linspace(0, 2)
    x2 = x1**x
    
    pyplot.plot(x1, x2, label=fr"$x^{x}$")
    
    x2 = x1**(-x)
    pyplot.plot(x1, x2, label=fr"x$^{-x}$")

pyplot.xlim(-0.1, 2)
pyplot.ylim(-0.1, 3)
pyplot.legend()
pyplot.show()
```

Which outputs as:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeHzh.png)

I was expecting that the inputted variable '-x' would be completely superscripted. I have tried to change the variable outside of the pyplot.plot() however run into the same error.

Answer (score 1):

In latex you can do it with `^{...}`, so try:

```
label=fr"$x^{{{x}}}$"
```

so the string looks like e.g. `'$x^{-2}$'`

Comment: Damn you deleted your comment while I was voting on it. Happy 10k ;)

Comment: @mozway Hah. Thanks. Realized that it is an actual answer, so moved it here :)